# Filtering results of query in PFQueryTableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, parse-platform, pfquery

I have a PFQueryTableViewController set up to retreive a list of objects satisfying a set of basic constraints when the view is loaded Below is the method that implements the query.

```
 - (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
     //The base query.
     self.query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
     [self.query includeKey:@"photos"];
     [self.query includeKey:@"user"];
     [self.query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
     [self.query whereKey:@"ordered" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:false]];
//     [query whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:self.currentLocation withinKilometers:32.2];
     // If Pull To Refresh is enabled, query against the network by default.
     if (self.pullToRefreshEnabled) {
         self.query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
     }

     // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
     if (self.objects.count == 0) {
         self.query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
     }


     return self.query;
 }
```

However, I also want to give the user the option to filter the results. 
The code I am using to try and filter is not working, as the list of objects doesn't change.

```
[self clear];
[self.query whereKey:@"cuisine" equalTo:cuisine.text];
[self loadObjects];
```

These instructions are embedded in a `UIAlertController` that contains a `UITextField` called `cuisine`

Why isn't the filter going through?

Thanks,
Siddharth

Answer (score 1):

Every time you execute loadObjects it will get a new query via queryForTable:

Try this:

```
-(void)search
{
    [self clear];

    //include this if you want to clear the query before applying the new filter
    self.query = [self startingQuery];
    [self.query whereKey:@"cuisine" equalTo:cuisine.text];
    [self loadObjects];
}
-(PFQuery *)query
{
    if (!_query) _query = [self startingQuery];
    return _query;
}

- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {
    return self.query;
}
-(PFQuery *)startingQuery
{
    //The base query.
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:self.parseClassName];
    [query includeKey:@"photos"];
    [query includeKey:@"user"];
    [query orderByDescending:@"createdAt"];
    [query whereKey:@"ordered" equalTo:[NSNumber numberWithBool:false]];
    //     [query whereKey:@"location" nearGeoPoint:self.currentLocation withinKilometers:32.2];
    // If Pull To Refresh is enabled, query against the network by default.
    if (self.pullToRefreshEnabled) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyNetworkOnly;
    }

    // If no objects are loaded in memory, we look to the cache first to fill the table
    // and then subsequently do a query against the network.
    if (self.objects.count == 0) {
        query.cachePolicy = kPFCachePolicyCacheThenNetwork;
    }


    return query;
}
```